# Issue with perspective projection

Tags: perspective

I have the following problem. [Perspective projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection) is often referred to when talking about camera models. I don’t think I understand it very well though this concept is taught when I was at junior high or even primary school. I think programmers with a computer vision background may be familiar with it.

I read quite some “tutorials” on perspective projection, also computer vision textbooks like “Computer Vision: Algorithms and Applications”, “Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision:Second Edition”. But the representation conventions seems to be quite a lot. It’s a little bit unfriendly to beginners. Just to get a feeling, here’s one of them:
[example formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmQtT.png)

May I ask if there’s some good, easy-to-read and self-contained articles that can help beginners like me understand perspective projection? It may explains quite clearly the physical meaning of the parameters of it, especially the “scale factor”.

Any ideas? Thanx in advance.

Comment: Check this out: http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html

Comment: In general, questions requesting resources are off-topic here. You could salvage this question by removing the request for off-site resources and just ask for an explanation here.